# How can I install Sun Java JDK 6 on Debian?

Tags: debian, java

If I try to install Sun Java JDK 6 on Debian, it doesn't install it. I don't want to install OpenJDK, because it doesn't work always exactly same as Sun JDK.

I use following command:

apt-get install sun-java6-jdk

Package name should be correct, see link http://packages.debian.org/sid/sun-java6-jdk.

Comment: An error message would help in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Run `sudo apt-cache search java6` to get a list of packages available from the default repositories. If you don't see anything you like, you will have to either add an apt repository or install java manually.

Answer (score 2):

**Update: I would probably use one of the JDK 6 builds from https://www.azul.com/downloads/zulu/zulu-linux/ now. Azul runs tests to make make sure the OpenJDK build is compliant, and also offers commercial support**

Assuming *Debian* means Debian Jessie.

I used the tool https://wiki.debian.org/JavaPackage to create a deb from the legacy JDK 6 provided by Oracle for the purposes of debugging older systems.

### Steps

1. Download the JDK 6 from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase6-419409.html. You will need an Oracle user account.
2. Install java-package from contrib. (Add contrib to your /etc/apt/sources.list if necessary)

   ```
   deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie main contrib
   deb-src http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie main contrib

   deb http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main contrib
   deb-src http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main contrib

   $ sudo apt-get && sudo apt-get install java-package.
   ```
3. Run make-jpkg on Oracle archive.

   ```
   make-jpkg /vagrant/jdk-6u45-linux-x64.bin
   ```
4. Install package

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i oracle-java6-jdk_6u45_amd64.deb
   ```
5. Make sure that JDK 6 is the default JDK if you have multiple.

   ```
   sudo update-alternatives --config javac
   ```
6. Check that everything works.

   ```
    [09:00]  [alex@debian-jessie:~]  $ javac -version
    javac 1.6.0_45

    [09:00]  [alex@debian-jessie:~]  $ java -version
    java version "1.6.0_45"
    Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_45-b06)
    Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.45-b01, mixed mode)

    [09:01]  [alex@debian-jessie:~]  $ mvn -v
    Apache Maven 3.0.5
    Maven home: /usr/share/maven
    Java version: 1.6.0_45, vendor: Sun Microsystems Inc.
    Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-6-oracle-x64/jre
    Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
    OS name: "linux", version: "3.16.0-4-amd64", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
   ```
7. To also install JRE 6, follow steps 1-6.

Answer (score 1):

The Sun (well, Oracle) Java packages are in the non-free repository, which you may have disabled (not sure off the top of my head whether it's enabled by default in sid).  Make sure non-free is enabled in your `/etc/apt/sources.list`, then run an `apt-get update`.

Answer (score -1):

Are you running as root?  Otherwise you'd need to use `sudo` to elevate yourself to have sufficient privileges to make system wide installations.